# Why don't NumPy floats give ZeroDivisionError?

Tags: python, exception, numpy

I noticed that in the code:

```
import numpy as np    

a = 0.0
print a / a

b = np.array( [0.0] )
print b[0] / b[0]
```

the first print function throws a ZeroDivisionError, but the second one outputs `nan`.  I'm aware that `type(b[0])` is `numpy.float64`, while `type(a)` is `float`.  I have two questions:

1) Why was it implemented this way?

2) Is there anyway to have it throw a ZeroDivisionError?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I must say, I am more surprised that the regular Python floats do throw an error. As far as I can understand, returning `NaN` is the correct way, given the way floats are defined in IEEE 754.

http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#exceptions

> *Why doesn't division by zero (or overflow, or underflow) stop the program or trigger an error? Why does a standard on numbers include "not-a-number" (`NaN`)?*
>
> The 754 model encourages robust programs. It is intended not only for numerical analysts but also for spreadsheet users, database systems, or even coffee pots. The propagation rules for `NaN`s and infinities allow inconsequential exceptions to vanish. Similarly, gradual underflow maintains error properties over a precision's range.
>
> When exceptional situations need attention, they can be examined immediately via traps or at a convenient time via status flags. Traps can be used to stop a program, but unrecoverable situations are extremely rare. Simply stopping a program is not an option for embedded systems or network agents. More often, traps log diagnostic information or substitute valid results.
>
> Flags offer both predictable control flow and speed. Their use requires the programmer be aware of exceptional conditions, but flag stickiness allows programmers to delay handling exceptional conditions until necessary.

An error is an appropriate response when dealing with numbers that do not have such capabilities, such as integral division.

Comment: In 754-speak, CPython enables the overflow, invalid operation, and divide-by-0 exceptions by default. The idea that most users have the slightest idea what to do with a NaN or infinity is absurd, and by enabling those 3 exceptions CPython ensures that a NaN or infinity is never created from finite inputs. You may *want* different behavior, and if so the `decimal` module can be told to do just about anything.  But Python's floats are implemented by the platform C's "double", and even decades after its introduction cross-platform C support for all the IEEE-754 gimmicks is still a nightmare.

Comment: @TimPeters I don't understand what the *default* behavior has to do with these answers. Programmers should be empowered to to handle exceptions in x way or y way.  But by *default*, coders like me only care whether numpy makes my life easy or hard, and `0/0` stopping code execution and supplying a line number helped me debug.  numpy's warning, on the other hand, got lost in debug print statements and made it take hours to understand where the `NaN`s in my array were coming from.  Therefore, I think the numpy devs should change the default behavior

Answer (score 5):

To answer the second part of your question, just use [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) numpy function.

So I had your problem and to cure it I simply put `np.seterr(all='raise')` right after my `import numpy as np` statement.

Thereafter my `try/except` block around the statement that was generating a zero error worked.

This approach works if you're dividing an array by an array (using numpy's "broadcasting" or coordinatewise math scheme): it throws the error even if only one of the divisions is by zero.

Comment: Good call.  Strange that numpy raises a `FloatingPointError` instead of Python's builtin `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: @Garrett I took your suggestion and did away with the paragraph. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Amadan's answer is why it is this way. If you do want it to throw a `ZeroDivisionError`, you can use

```
if np.isnan(x):
    raise ZeroDivisionError
```

where x is the value you're checking. Like other numpy functions, though, `np.isnan()` takes a numpy array as an input and returns a boolean numpy array as output. So if you have `myNumPyArray`, you can use `myNumPyArray[np.isnan(myNumPyArray]` to show all of the NaN elements, or `myNumPyArray[np.invert(np.isnan(myNumPyArray))]` to show the non-NaN elements